# TeamCity build agent with multiple version of Qt

Tags: qt, teamcity

We have the TeamCity build cloud with several computers and one of the computer runs on Linux with Qt install. We have several Qt projects and these project use different versions of Qt. For example:

- project1 -> needs Qt 4.3
- project2 -> needs Qt 5.0
- project3 -> needs Qt 5.2

It would be nice to build all these project on this computer (build agent).

Is it possible somehow to make such build agent compatible to multiple Qt versions? How to configure Qt and TeamCity in such way?

Answer (score 2):

**Aproach 1**
 You can configure your teamcity project to run on specific teamcity agents . For ex

```
project1 -> teamcity-agent-qt4.3
project2 -> teamcity-agent-qt
project3 -> teamcity-agent-qt5.2
```

You can then configure [Teamcity Agent startup properties](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Agent+Startup+Properties) for each agent to run on the specific qt version

**Approach 2**
In case you have a mechanism to dynamically source a qt version at runtime, you can add a parameter for the qt path in the `build parameters` section of the project and use that to run with the appropriate qt version in the build.